# Should I leave or remove the big white foam on top of the hard drive case?

Tags: hard-drive, case

I received a new Corsair Airflow tower. The case for storing hard drives came stuck in place with a big chunk of white foam (or whatever material this is).

I'm wondering whether this should either:

- stay in place to reduce vibrations
- be removed (risk of fire?)

As I don't find any mention of it either in the manual or online, I'm wondering whether this is there just for shipping or if it should legit stay in place.

An image of the material can be found here

[image]

Comment: Probably styrofoam.  Carefully remove it.

Comment: Pic?  Its difficult to envisage what you are saying.

Comment: You can also always contact the seller and ask them. They should know if the styrofoam is to be removed or not. I bet it was placed for shipping purposes.

Comment: Looks like this: https://ibb.co/XzBFwkm

Comment: That is packing styrofoam.

Comment: it's not styrofoam ... probably polypropylene ... it is packing material that you can remove

Answer (score 3):

According to the manual available from https://res.cloudinary.com/corsair-pwa/image/upload/corsairmedia/sys_master/productcontent/WW_4000D_4000D_Airflow_QSG_AB.pdf, there are no foam parts included in the stated parts list; only screws, spacers, cable ties, and stand-offs.

The piece of material you're referring to is likely used to prevent the glass panel from making contact with the HDD caddy or to prevent the caddy from working itself loose in transit.

It can be disposed of, or recycled.